# How do I get thousands of PDF files "found" by google search

Tags: php, seo, google-search

I have approximately 5,000 PDF files in 4 different categories on our Joomla website that are currently only accessible by via a PHP/mySQL seach script.   The filenames (which are numbers) and file locations are stored in a mySQL db and there is a simple PHP script that sends the query and returns a hyperlink to the correct file.  The seach is based on a user typing in a number which corresponds to the filename (people using this will know what the number represents - it's a legal case number).

I'd love for the files to be accessible via a google search but I'm not clear about how to make google find them.  Should I just create a text page for each of the 4 categories which contain the links to each of the files and make those easily accessible by google's search?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: There a few different ways to approach this. Yes, an XML sitemap is the goal, but how to build the sitemap?  There are two basic methods I think: 1) write some php code or use a joomla plugin that will output all the db records (php file locations of the pdfs) into a sitemap and 2) all the pdfs must be in directories - put that directory in a sitemap or use an oneline sitemap tool to generate it.

Comment: The file locations of the pdf's are independent of the joomla site - in their own db and unknown  to the joomla db.  So it appears your second solution is the best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add them to your [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/). It's more than for HTML files.